# Got error when setting read_batch_size in tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples. default is ok

Tags: tensorflow

I modified code of the wide & deep tutorial for reading large input from file using tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples. For speeding up the training process, I set the read_batch_size and got an error **ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([]), TensorShape([Dimension(None)])]**
My piece of code：

```
def input_fn_pre(batch_size, filename):
  examples_op = tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples(
    filename,
    batch_size=5000,
    reader=tf.TextLineReader,
    num_epochs=5,
    num_threads=5,
    read_batch_size=2500,
    parse_fn=lambda x: tf.decode_csv(x, [tf.constant(['0'], dtype=tf.string)] * len(COLUMNS) * 2500, use_quote_delim=False))                                  
  examples_dict = {}

  for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
    examples_dict[col] = examples_op[:, i]
  feature_cols = {k: tf.string_to_number(examples_dict[k], out_type=tf.float32) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
  feature_cols.update({k: dense_to_sparse(examples_dict[k]) for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS})
  label = tf.string_to_number(examples_dict[LABEL_COLUMN], out_type=tf.int32)
  return feature_cols, label
```

while using the default parameter setting is ok:

```
def input_fn_pre(batch_size, filename):
  examples_op = tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_examples(
    filename,
    batch_size=5000,
    reader=tf.TextLineReader,
    num_epochs=5,
    num_threads=5,
    parse_fn=lambda x: tf.decode_csv(x, [tf.constant(['0'], dtype=tf.string)] * len(COLUMNS), use_quote_delim=False))                                  
  examples_dict = {}

  for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
    examples_dict[col] = examples_op[:, i]
  feature_cols = {k: tf.string_to_number(examples_dict[k], out_type=tf.float32) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
  feature_cols.update({k: dense_to_sparse(examples_dict[k]) for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS})
  label = tf.string_to_number(examples_dict[LABEL_COLUMN], out_type=tf.int32)
  return feature_cols, label
```

There is not enough explanation in the tensorflow doc.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any difference between your two code snippets. Could you update your code?

Comment: The error is not obvious by just reading the code. Could you post your minimal complete (runnable) code?